# Populating dropdown and adding new row to db with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I want to add a post with category, my `Add` action in `BlogController` is like this :

```
private readonly IBlogPostRepository _blogPostRepository;
private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;

public BlogController()
        {
            _blogPostRepository = new BlogPostRepository(new SiteContext());
            _categoryRepository = new CategoryRepository(new SiteContext());
        }


        public BlogController(IBlogPostRepository blogPostRepository, ICategoryRepository      categoryRepository)
        {
            _blogPostRepository = blogPostRepository;
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        }

        public ActionResult Add()
        {
            ViewData["categoryList"] = _categoryRepository.GetAllCategory();
            return View("Add");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(BlogPost blogPost)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                blogPost.PublishDate = DateTime.Now;

                _blogPostRepository.AddPost(blogPost);
                _blogPostRepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Add");
            }
            return new HttpNotFoundResult("An Error Accoured while requesting your order!");
        }
```

My first question is that why I can't cast category list to `SelectList` in razor to select a category via `DropDownList`? My code in view is like this:

```
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(b => b.Category)
        @Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewData["categoryList"] as SelectList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(b => b.Category)
    </div>
```

My second question is: how can I add category in `Add` action with `POST` request?

Comment: you CAN cast the Viewdata. You're doing it wrong. are you using c# or vb?

Comment: the best way to add a category is to re-render the dropdown. You can use other way like JQuery, but thats the cleanest.

Comment: I'm using C# , How can I cast ? I got this Error :  There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Category'.  what is this ??

Comment: The question is; what is your `GetAllCategory` method returning? If it's returning anything other than a [`SelectList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.100).aspx), then it would be `null` (after the cast) and fail.

Comment: the cast for a selectlist would look like (SelectList) ViewData["categoryList"]. Assuming, as @KristianHellang pointed out, that you have created a select list.

Comment: @DaveA That's not entirely right, it's perfectly fine to do a cast using the `as` keyword.

Comment: @KristianHellang, didn't know that. thanx. then the issue is either Eric is sending back a simple List of empty data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a collection for a dropdown, it has to be of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, which `SelectList` is. You can't take an arbitrary collection of objects and just cast it to a `SelectList`.

I like to use an extension method for creating an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, check out this:

```cs
public static class SelectListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return ToSelectList(source, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string defaultOption)
    {
        return ToSelectList(source, value => value, value => value.ToString(), null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T, TDataValue>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, TDataValue> dataValueSelector,
        Func<T, string> dataTextSelector)
    {
        return ToSelectList(source, (value, index) => dataValueSelector(value), dataTextSelector, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T, TDataValue>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, int, TDataValue> dataValueSelector,
        Func<T, string> dataTextSelector)
    {
        return ToSelectList(source, dataValueSelector, dataTextSelector, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T, TDataValue>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, TDataValue> dataValueSelector,
        Func<T, string> dataTextSelector,
        string defaultOption)
    {
        return ToSelectList(source, (value, index) => dataValueSelector(value), dataTextSelector, defaultOption);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T, TDataValue>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        Func<T, int, TDataValue> dataValueSelector,
        Func<T, string> dataTextSelector,
        string defaultOption)
    {
        var list = source.Select((item, index) => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = dataValueSelector(item, index).ToString(),
            Text = dataTextSelector(item),
        }).ToList();

        if (defaultOption == null) return list;

        list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = defaultOption, Value = "-1" });

        return list;
    }
}
```

You can then use this extension method in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    ViewData["categoryList"] = _categoryRepository.GetAllCategory()
        .ToSelectList(c => c.Id, c => c.Name);

    return View("Add");
}
```

Assuming that your `Category` has the properties `Id` and `Name`...

And then use it in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category", ViewData["categoryList"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

On a side note, I would recommend that you use models to pass to your (strongly typed) views, as opposed to using `ViewData`/`ViewBag`. It saves you a lot of trouble the day you're going to refactor something and it also gives you good tooling help (intellisense).

Comment: thanks Kristian! I just checked it and it works now ,don't you have any Idea add this category (when I select it dropdown) and assign it to a post ? how can I do that ? please

Comment: To get the selected category, you will either need to have a model that will be bound to the value, or get the value (using the name of your dropdown) as an action method parameter.

Comment: I don't have any problem about binding category to action , but the main problem is that I cant create category for blogpost !

Comment: I don't understand your problem... You get the selected category id in the action, you query the category repository to get the selected category and assign it to the post before saving it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: well , I had two problem that you answered one of them(selectlist one) another one id that I don't know how to assign this category to a post before saving it , take a look at my add action , how can I add selected category to a blogpost , please

Comment: That's what I was trying to tell you. Since your dropdown is called "Category", MVC will try to bind the selected value to an action method parameter called "Category" or, in your case, a property on the `BlogPost` called "Category". If there is no such property on `BlogPost`, you can either use the [`BindAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) to bind the value, or take an extra, `int category` in the action method (assuming that the selected value is an `int`. Then just get the category from the repo and set it before saving.